# PHP - text not added to a variable inside foreach loop

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, wordpress-plugin-creation

I have this code in my WordPress plugin, it's supposed to get some data from database and after that send emails to different adresses with a common subject but different email body.

```php
<?php

$pdv_subject = "Confirmation links from" . date('d-m-Y', time());
//
$pdv_message_a = "Salut!\n";
$pdv_email_a = 'user@example.com';
$pdv_headers_a[] = 'Cc: user@example.com';

//
$pdv_message_b = "Ciao!\n";
$pdv_email_b = 'user@example.com';
$pdv_headers_b[] = 'Cc: user@example.com';


//
$pdv_message_p = "Hello!\n";
$pdv_email_p = 'user@example.com';
$pdv_headers_p[] = 'Cc: user@example.com';


//
foreach( $results as $key => $val ){
    if(date('d-m-Y', $val['confirmed_at']) === date('d-m-Y', time()) && $val['pco'] === '650'){
        $pdv_message_a .= $val['link'] . "\n";
    } 
    //
    if(date('d-m-Y', $val['confirmed_at']) === date('d-m-Y', time()) && $val['pco'] === '620'){
        $pdv_message_b .= $val['link'] . "\n";
    }
    // 
    if(date('d-m-Y', $val['confirmed_at']) === date('d-m-Y', time()) && $val['pco'] === '660' ){
        $pdv_message_p .= $val['link'] . "\n";
    }
}
```

In the code I've omitted the `wp_mail` function, I've done a test and it's working fine. The only problem I have is that the `$pdv_message_` that needs to be added inside the if statement will be not added, this will cause that the email will be sent without the links inside the body. I've done a `var_dump()` and I'm able to see the `$val` but why the links aren't added to the messages?

Comment: Is it an operator precedence thing? Does it make any difference if you surround the `$val['pco'] === '650'` section in parentheses, as in `&& ($val['pco'] === '650')` ? And the same for the first comparison?

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal example, with the values in $result? Can you confirm that you run into the "if" statements?

Comment: Have you tried doing `echo $val['link']`? Maybe it's empty and that's why it's "not adding" it to variable. I would do `echo $val['link']` before if statements. If it's not empty then you should check your logic of if statements.

Comment: @droopsnoot no, I just need to check that the value stored is equal to each code to assign the links correctly to the desired message

Comment: @mhaendler `$result` is an associative array returned from `get_post_meta()` function. I've already checked the values returned and I can confirm that all the values stored inside the database are returned from the function

Comment: @Korovjov as I said in a previous comment, all the values are returned inside the `$result` variable that will hold an associative array. Already tested the `$val['link']` using `var_dump()` and I can confirm that the link are displayed correctly

Comment: The easiest way to help you with your problem is still a minimal example, please provide dump of $val for example. For me the issue might be the "confirmed_at" date is not today, so the if is false and appending the link will not get executed. maybe date can't recognize the date format provided from "confirmed_at" and you have to convert it via strtotime  - ```date('d-m-Y', strtotime($val['confirmed_at']))```.

btw ```date()``` doesn't need ```time()``` as second parameter, as if nothing is provided it uses ```time()``` as default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from anything, I think I'd lay the code out like this

```
foreach( $results as $key => $val ){
  if(date('d-m-Y', $val['confirmed_at']) === date('d-m-Y', time())) { 
    switch ($val['pco']) {
      case '620':
        $pdv_message_b .= $val['link'] . "\n";
        break;
      case '650':     
        $pdv_message_a .= $val['link'] . "\n";
        break;
      case '660':
        $pdv_message_p .= $val['link'] . "\n";
        break;  
        }
    }
}
```

(I'm not suggesting this is an answer to your problem, but it looks a lot nicer IMO and saves repeating all those identical if clauses.)

Comment: ok, i avoided to use the switch statement but thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Maybe those `$pdv_message_X` variables should be an array to begin with. They could use the `$val['pco']` value as key, making the whole switch superfluous as well, it could simply be replaced with `in_array` then to check if the value was one of 620, 650 or 660.